# Cumulative count instead of last file

Tags: r, for-loop, count

I am trying to count all of the files cumulatively, but for some reason it is instead counting the last file and using that number for the rest of the analysis. How can I change this code to instead include the counts and unique counts of all files (there are 51 files).

```
#Move all files to one list
file_list <- list.files(pattern="Dataset 2.*txt")

Read files
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
file <- read.table(file_list[i], header=TRUE, sep=",")
out.file <- rbind(file)
}

Count total number phone call records
count_PHONECALLRECORDS <- length(out.file$CALLER_ID)

#Count number unique caller id's
count_CALLERID <- length(unique(out.file$CALLER_ID))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the correction you need -

```
# Read files
out.file <- NULL
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
  file <- read.table(file_list[i], header=TRUE, sep=",")
  out.file <- rbind(out.file, file)
}
```

Note that this way of *growing* the data i.e rbind-ing to itself is not efficient but assuming you are a beginner I'd say don't worry about it until you have to.

Comment: Add a small sample of your data from one of the files to your post. Hard to help without it.

Answer (score 0):

You should move the counting code to the loop and initialize the counting variables before the loop:

```
setwd("~/Desktop/GEOG Research/Jordan/compression")
library(plyr)
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)

# Move all files to one list
file_list <- list.files(pattern="Dataset 2.*txt")

# Read files
count_PHONECALLRECORDS <- 0
count_CALLERID <- 0
for (i in 1:length(file_list)){
   file <- read.table(file_list[i], header=TRUE, sep=",")
   out.file <- rbind(file)

   # Count total number phone call records
   count_PHONECALLRECORDS <- count_PHONECALLRECORDS + length(out.file$CALLER_ID)

   # Count number unique caller id's
   count_CALLERID <- count_CALLERID + length(unique(out.file$CALLER_ID))
}

# Construct contingency matrix
tb_1 <- with(out.file, table(CALLEE_PREFIX, CALLER = substr(CALLER_ID, 0, 1)))
colnames(tb_1) <- c("Refugee Caller", "Non-Refugee Caller")
rownames(tb_1) <- c("Refugee Callee", "Non-Refugee Callee", "Unknown Callee")
tb_1
```

Comment: Thank you! I added the above user's code to this (initializing out.file <- 0 and then out.file <- rbind(out.file, file), but am getting different results for out.file and count_PHONECALLRECORDS when they should be the same. Any idea why this might be?